# How to calculate standard errors in the finite mixture model

Tags: panel-data, standard-error, finite-mixture-model

I have a panel dataset, and I am estimating a self-defined likelihood function using finite mixture model.

$$
L_i(\theta)=p\prod^T_tL(y_{it}(\theta)|type1)  + (1-p)\prod^T_tL(y_{it}(\theta)|type2)
$$

$$
Log L(\theta)=\sum^N_ilog(L_i(\theta))
$$

My dataset has three levels, individual, group, and treatment. I am doing the estimation at the three levels separately. For the individual level data, I am trying to use HAC standard error, for the group level data I am trying to use Driscoll and Kraay standard errors, for the treatment level data, I am using cluster standard error.

Without finite mixture feature, we have $Log L=\sum^N\sum^T log L_{it}(\theta)$
and we can calculate the HAC standard error using the squared root of the following:
$$
A^{-1}BA^{-1}
$$
where
$$
A=\frac{\partial^2 Log L(\theta)}{\partial \theta\partial \theta'}
$$
$$
B=\Omega_0+\sum^{m(T)}_{j=1}w(j,m)[\Omega_j+\Omega_j']
$$
$$w(j,m(T))=1-j/(m(T)+1)$$
$$
\Omega_j=\sum^T_{t=j+1}s_{it}s_{it-j}', s_{it}=\frac{\partial Log L_{it}(\theta)}{\partial \theta}
$$

To calculate Driscoll and Kraay standard errors, we can replace $s_{it}$ with cluster sum of score vectors.

My question is, if I use finite mixture model in the way specified above, for the estimations using individual and group level data, how should I calculate the HAC and D-K standard error, specifically how should I calculate the score vector as there is (kind of) no t dimension?

From the Stata Manual, the cluster robust standard error is calculated as follows:
$$
-A^{-1}(\sum^M_{k=1} u^{G'}_k u^G_k)(-A)^{-1}
$$
where $u_k$ is the contribution to the $k$th group to $\partial log L/\partial \theta$. If the log-likelihood function is addictive in the observation $j$ (equivalent to observation $it$), then
$$
u_k = \sum_{j\in G_k} u_j, \ u_j=\frac{\partial log L_j}{\partial \theta}
$$
My understanding of this is that if my log likelihood is not entirely additive as the one in the finite mixture model specified above, then when calculating the cluster robust standard error,
$$
u_k = \sum_{i\in G_k} u_i, u_i=\frac{\partial log L_i}{\partial \theta}
$$
Is this correct?
Or I have to go for bootstrapping standard error?